# Edit and display variable in php file from javascript on html web page

Tags: javascript, php, html, variables

What I'm looking to to is create a variable in a php file on my server called "likes"

Then, on my html web page, I want to have a like button, that when clicked used javascript to edit the variable "likes" in that php file and adds 1.
There will be a little place on the page above the like button that shows the total number of likes.

WHAT I HAVE:

PHP FILE: "index.php"

```
<?php
$likes=0;

/** Load likes page START */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/likespagestart.html' );
echo $likes;
/** Load likes page END */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/likespageend.html' );
?>
```

HTML FILE: "likepagestart.html"

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Likes Page</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
var count = 0;
function countClicks() {
 count = count + 1;
    document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML = count;
}
</script>

</head>

<body>
This is the likes page!
<br/>
Number of likes: <p id="p2">0</p>
```

HTML FILE: "likepageend.html"

```
<br/>
<a href="javascript:countClicks();">Like</a>
</body>
</html>
```

View on my website: www.stevenhower.com/phpinclude/likes (The first 0 is the javascript only, the second 0 is the php variable.

So right now, I just have a silly javascript function, and can't actually edit the variable in the php file...

Comment: Can you show some attempt at solving this problem? S.O. works best when users can help you modify your code rather than just write solutions for you.

Comment: While this isn't a huge application, there are quite a lot of separate parts to it. What problem are you having and with which part?

Comment: I think you will need to use ajax.

Comment: You will need to use AJAX or POST back the information to a php handler.

Comment: I've updated the question with what I have. Thank you all for your time so far :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a url that will handle all the backend logic to update your 'likes' and then create an ajax call with a post method to hit that url. I recommend using the jQuery javascript framework with this method: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url:'/update_likes.php',
  data: {
   'likes': updated_counter
  },
  success: function(){
   // Update view logic
  },
  dataType: 'json'
});
```

Something like that

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Any way you could look at the code in my post, and update this code to function with the content I have? I've tried and can't seem to get it...